# $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c+abc=4$. Prove that: $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}\ge 3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, uvw

> Problem. Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c+abc=4$. Prove that: $$\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a+bc}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b+ca}}\ge 3.$$

I think the problem is nice and very hard. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=1; (0,2,2).$

The idea of using AM-GM directly doesn't work, because $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge (a+bc)(b+ca)(c+ab),$$is wrong when $a=b=\dfrac{3}{2}.$

Also: $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{2(a+b)}{a+b+c+ab},$$leads to wrong inequality.

Is Holder inequality is a good way in this case ?

I tried $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(a+b)^2(c+ab)\ge 8(a+b+c)^3,$$which is not good enough.

I think Mixing variables is a good approach but I am not good at using this method.

A fact: $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b+c}{a+bc}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c+a}{b+ca}}\ge 3,$$is already wrong when $a=b=1.874$.

Hope to see more ideas. Thank you.

Comment: You got answers for several of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Oh, it is very important. Thank you for reminding me

Comment: Even by $ab+bc+ca=3$, the problem is hard already

Comment: I think the problem is too hard. Is there a original proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**.

By Holder, we have
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}\right)^2
 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b)^2(c + ab)(c + 2)^3
 \ge{} \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b)(c + 2)\right)^3.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b)(c + 2)\right)^3
\ge 9 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + b)^2(c + ab)(c + 2)^3. \tag{1} $$
This inequality is true which is verified by Mathematica. It can be proved by the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

The condition $a + b + c + abc = 4$ becomes $p + r = 4$.

Using $r = 4- p$, (1) is written as
\begin{align*}
 &208\,{q}^{3}+ \left( -72\,{p}^{2}+96\,p-2304 \right) {q}^{2}+ \left( 
 480\,{p}^{2}-5616\,p+15552 \right) q\\
 &\quad +2384\,{p}^{3}-14184\,{p}^{2}+
 34560\,p-31104
 \ge 0.
\end{align*}

Omitted.

Comment: This answer is the best here

Comment: @TATAbox It is still complicated.

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: Since no verified proof is available, I give a proof. It is a computer assisted proof. It is very complicated by hand. Hope to see nice proofs.

**Sketch of a proof**.

Let
$$x := \frac{a + b}{c + ab},
\quad y := \frac{b + c}{a + bc},
\quad z := \frac{c + a}{b + ca},$$
$$u := \frac{2(a + b)}{ab + a + b + c},
\quad v := \frac{2(b + c)}{bc + a + b + c}, \quad w := \frac{2(c + a)}{ca + a + b + c}.$$

By AM-GM, we have $u = \frac{2x}{1 + x} \le \sqrt x$, $v = \frac{2y}{1+y} \le \sqrt{y}$,
and $w = \frac{2z}{1+z}\le \sqrt{z}$.

We have
$$\sqrt{x} - u = \frac{x - u^2}{\sqrt{x} + u} \ge \frac{x - u^2}{\frac{x + 1}{2} + u}. \tag{1}$$

Using (1), it suffices to prove that
$$u + \frac{x - u^2}{\frac{x + 1}{2} + u} + v + \frac{y - v^2}{\frac{y + 1}{2} + v} + w + \frac{z - w^2}{\frac{z + 1}{2} + w} \ge 3. \tag{2}$$

We use pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

The condition $a + b + c + abc = 4$ is written as
$$p + r = 4. \tag{3}$$

(2) is written as
\begin{align*}
 &5\,{p}^{6}+10\,{p}^{5}q-62\,{p}^{5}r+{p}^{4}{q}^{2}-14\,{p}^{4}qr-3\,{
  p}^{4}{r}^{2}+24\,{p}^{4}q\\
 &\quad +144\,{p}^{4}r-16\,{p}^{3}{q}^{2}+48\,{p}^{3
 }qr-126\,{p}^{3}{r}^{2}-8\,{p}^{2}{q}^{3}-8\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}r\\
&\quad -30\,{p}^{
  2}q{r}^{2}-6\,{p}^{2}{r}^{3}-96\,{p}^{3}r+16\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+288\,{p}^
 {2}qr+252\,{p}^{2}{r}^{2}\\
 &\quad -224\,p{q}^{3}+384\,p{q}^{2}r+72\,pq{r}^{2}-
 64\,p{r}^{3}-48\,{q}^{4}+64\,{q}^{3}r+8\,{q}^{2}{r}^{2}\\
 &\quad -16\,q{r}^{3}-3
 \,{r}^{4}-256\,pqr-352\,p{r}^{2}+128\,{q}^{2}r-320\,q{r}^{2}+96\,{r}^{
  3}+192\,{r}^{2}\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{4}
\end{align*}

From (3), using $r = 4 - p$, (4) is written as
\begin{align*}
 &-48\,{q}^{4}+ \left( -8\,{p}^{2}-288\,p+256 \right) {q}^{3}+ \left( {p
 }^{4}-8\,{p}^{3}-392\,{p}^{2}+1344\,p+640 \right) {q}^{2}\\
&\quad + \left( 24\,
 {p}^{5}-110\,{p}^{4}+232\,{p}^{3}-160\,{p}^{2}+3456\,p-6144 \right) q \\
 &\quad +
 64\,{p}^{6}-488\,{p}^{5}+1873\,{p}^{4}-5296\,{p}^{3}+10592\,{p}^{2}-
 15104\,p+8448\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{5}
\end{align*}

From (3), we have $3 \le p \le 4$.

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$ and (3),
we have $q \ge \sqrt{3p(4 - p)}$.

Using degree four Schur inequality $r \ge \frac{5p^2q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p}$ and (3), we have
$$4 - p \ge \frac{5p^2q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p}$$
which results in (using $p^2 \ge 3q$)
$$q \le \frac58 p^2 - \frac18\sqrt{9p^4 + 96p^2 - 384p}.$$

Thus, we have
$$3 \le p \le 4, \quad \sqrt{3p(4 - p)} \le q \le \frac58 p^2 - \frac18\sqrt{9p^4 + 96p^2 - 384p}. \tag{6}$$

If $q = \sqrt{3p(4 - p)}$, we can prove (5).

If $\sqrt{3p(4 - p)} < q \le \frac58 p^2 - \frac18\sqrt{9p^4 + 96p^2 - 384p}$, we use the Buffalo Way (BW).

Let
$$q_1 := \sqrt{3p(4 - p)}, \quad q_2 := \frac58 p^2 - \frac18\sqrt{9p^4 + 96p^2 - 384p}.$$

Let
$$s := \frac{q_2 - q}{q - q_1} \ge 0.$$
We have
$$q = q_1 \cdot \frac{s}{1 + s} + q_2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + s}. \tag{7}$$

We plug (7) into (5), after clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
$$m_4s^4 + m_3s^3 + m_2s^2 + m_1s + m_0 \ge 0 \tag{8}$$
where $m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4$ are functions in $p$.

We can prove that $m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4 \ge 0$ for all $3\le p\le 4$. Thus, (8) is true.

We are done.

Comment: Oustanding proof! +1

Comment: @TATAbox It is not nice. Perhaps someone has a tricky proof (tricky AM-GM etc.).

Comment: I agree. There is at least a nice proof in basically.

Comment: Sorry for spoil. Have you try to use isolated fudging for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749474/let-abc-3-then-prove-sqrt3-fracab5ab4-sqrt3-fraccb5cb4 ?
I try a lot by Holder without success.

Comment: @TATAbox I will try. I can only use isolated fudging of the form of rational functions i.e. ratio of two polynomials. Often it does not work.

Comment: My congratulation, @RiverLi. You deserve +250

Comment: @Dragonboy Thanks. As TATA box said, "There is at least a nice proof in basically". I think it is tricky.

Answer (score -1):

Let $g(a,b,c)=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c+ab}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a+bc}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b+ca}}$ and $f(a,b)=g(a,b,\frac{4-a-b}{1+ab})$ defined on the closed triangle except and with vertices $(0,0)$,$(4,0),(0,4)$. On boundry $f(a,b)$ reduces to the function $h(x)=\sqrt{\frac{4}{x(4-x)}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}+\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}$ where $0< x< 4$ and by symmetry principle its minumum is $3$ at $x=2$. On the interior of the triangle, by symmetry principle, minumum occurs when $a=b=x$ and  the problem reduces to finding the minumum of
$$p(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2x^3+2x}{x^4+x^2-2x+4}}+2\sqrt{\frac{x^3-x+4}{x^3-2x^2+5x}}$$ where $0<x<2$. And the minimum is $3$ at $x=1$. See the [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimum%20sqrt%28%282x%5E3%2B2x%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2-2x%2B4%29%29%2B2sqrt%28%28x%5E3-x%2B4%29%2F%28x%5E3-2x%5E2%2B5x%29%29%20where%200%3Cx%3C2).

Comment: How did you consider that ?

Comment: I was on holiday and bored.

Comment: This problem is really hard, indeed.

Comment: I am not experienced with the mentioned inequalites too much. So I dont see the difficulty level. I tried the calculus way again. But the expression is symmetric. Anti symmetric ones are not touchable.

Comment: You should complete your idea.

Answer (score -2):

Just few remarks :

We can plays without loss of generality with the constraint we have :

$$a+b+c+abc=4$$

Now plugging $$a=y(u-v)\geq 0,b=y(v-w)\geq 0,c=z(u-w)\geq 0$$

Then we can factor this constraint as we have :

$$a+b+c+abc=y(u-v)+y(v-w)+z(u-w)+y(u-v)\cdot y(v-w)\cdot z(u-w)=\left(u-w\right)\left(uvy^{2}z-uwy^{2}z-v^{2}y^{2}z+vwy^{2}z+y+z\right)=4$$

On the other hand the inequality becomes :

$\sqrt{\frac{y\left(u-w\right)}{z\left(u-w\right)+y^{2}\left(u-v\right)\left(v-w\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)}{y\left(u-v\right)+y\left(v-w\right)z\left(u-w\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{z\left(u-w\right)+y\left(u-v\right)}{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)y\left(u-v\right)}}\ge 3$

Trivial Case : $u\geq 1=v=w$ :

A bit of algebra plugging $u\to ux,v\to vx,w\to wx,y\to yx,z\to zx$and we have :

$$a+b+c+abc=4=(u-1)x^2(y+z)\tag{I}$$

Again a bit of algebra and we need to show :

$$\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}+\sqrt{\frac{z+y}{x^{2}zy\left(u-1\right)}}\ge 3$$

Or using $I$

$$\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}+\sqrt{\frac{4}{x^{3}zy\left(u-1\right)^{2}}}\geq 3$$

Now $y\to y^2,x\to x^2,z\to z^2,u\to u+1$ we need to show :

$$\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{2}{x^{3}zyu}\geq 3$$

Or :

$$\frac{\left(ux^{3}y^{2}-3ux^{3}yz+ux^{3}z^{2}+2\right)}{ux^{3}yz}\geq 0$$

Or :

$$\frac{\left(4x-3ux^{3}yz+2\right)}{ux^{3}yz}\geq 0$$

But $y^2+z^2\geq 2yz$ so we need to show :

$$\left(4x-\frac{3}{2}x+2\right)\geq 0$$

Wich is true !

Case : $u-v=v-w=1/2(u-w),\exists \varepsilon x,y,z\in[1+\varepsilon ,\infty),y\geq z$ (with the same substitution as in the trivial case)

Then we have :

$$a+b+c+abc=4=x^2(x^3y^2z+y+z)(u-w)$$

Then starting from :

$\sqrt{\frac{y\left(u-w\right)}{z\left(u-w\right)+x^2y^{2}\left(u-v\right)\left(v-w\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)}{y\left(u-v\right)+x^2y\left(v-w\right)z\left(u-w\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{z\left(u-w\right)+y\left(u-v\right)}{y\left(v-w\right)+x^2z\left(u-w\right)y\left(u-v\right)}}\ge 3$

Or :

$$\sqrt{\frac{y\left(u-w\right)}{z\left(u-w\right)+x^2y^{2}\left(u-v\right)\left(v-w\right)}}+2\sqrt{\frac{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)}{y\left(u-v\right)+x^2y\left(v-w\right)z\left(u-w\right)}}\ge 3$$

Or :

$$\sqrt{\frac{2y}{2z+x^2y^{2}\left(u-v\right)}}+2\sqrt{\frac{y+2z}{y\left(u-v\right)+2x^2y\left(v-w\right)z}}\ge 3$$

Or :

$$\sqrt{\frac{2y}{2z+2\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2(x^3y^2z+y+z)}}}+2\sqrt{\frac{y+2z}{y+4\frac{x^2yz}{x^2(x^3y^2z+y+z)}}}\ge 3$$

Or :

$$\sqrt{\frac{2y}{2z+2\frac{y^2}{(x^3y^2z+y+z)}}}+2\sqrt{\frac{y+2z}{y+4\frac{yz}{(x^3y^2z+y+z)}}}\ge 3\tag{J}$$

Now we introduce the inequality :

$$\sqrt{\frac{y}{z+\frac{y^{2}}{(xy^{2}z+y+z)}}}4\sqrt{\frac{y+2z}{y+4\frac{yz}{(xy^{2}z+y+z)}}}-3\geq 0$$

Or squaring :

$$f(x,y,z)=(16x^{2}y^{5}z^{2}+23x^{2}y^{4}z^{3}+23xy^{4}z+78xy^{3}z^{2}+10xy^{2}z^{3}+7y^{3}+10y^{2}z+26yz^{2}-13z^{3})/((xy^{2}z+y+5z)(xy^{2}z^{2}+y^{2}+yz+z^{2}))\ge 0$$

Now with a computer we have :

$$f(x,(y+z)/2,z)\geq 0$$

Now we can square $J$

Some idea to go further :

Replace in the first constraint :

$$\frac{uy-wy-4}{(u-w)(uy^2(w-v)+v^2y^2-vwy^2-1)}=z\tag{J}$$

Then use Am-Gm as we have :

$$Inequality to prove \geq 2\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{y(u-w)}{z(u-w)+y^2(u-v)(v-w)}} \sqrt{\frac{y(v-w)+z(u-w)}{y(u-v)+y(v-w)z(u-w)}}}+\sqrt{\frac{z\left(u-w\right)+y\left(u-v\right)}{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)y\left(u-v\right)}}$$

Now I think the inequality :

$$2\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{y(u-w)}{z(u-w)+y^2(u-v)(v-w)}} \sqrt{\frac{y(v-w)+z(u-w)}{y(u-v)+y(v-w)z(u-w)}}}+\sqrt{\frac{z\left(u-w\right)+y\left(u-v\right)}{y\left(v-w\right)+z\left(u-w\right)y\left(u-v\right)}}\geq 3$$

Is true with $J$ then we can try to conclude using Young's inequality for product and a computer .

I stop here .

Comment: Can you explain how that helps to prove the inequality? It seems that both the desired inequalily and the condition on $a,b, c$ become more complicated, not simpler.

Comment: Complexify first simplify next in maths we cannot walk always straight.

Comment: @MartinR I send you a message if I go further now i'm working on it .

Comment: @MartinR I made some progress can you lead  me to see if there anything wrong thanks !

Comment: You consider only the case $v=w$, i.e. the case that $b=0$. But then $a+c=4$ and you can simply use AM-GM:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{ca}} \ge 2 + \sqrt{\frac{4}{a+c}} =3 \, .
$$ I cannot see you your “Complexify first” leads to any simplification.

Comment: @MartinR see the new considered case which seems to be non trivial .

Comment: @MartinR I sketch the case where two unknows are equals what do you think about ?

Comment: How do we continue proof ?

Comment: @HaDiepXuan I give you some hint .

Comment: @ErikSatie Can you explain the next step which you want to attain ?

Comment: @TATAbox See my edit next your comment