# If $ab+bc+ca=3$, then prove that $\sum\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{bc+1}}\ge\frac{a+b+c+3}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, holder-inequality, uvw

> **Problem** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that$$\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{bc+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{ca+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}\ge\frac{a+b+c+3}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}.$$
> I saw the problem on AOPS.

I tried to use AM-GM which leads to wrong inequality$$3.\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{bc+1}}.\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{ca+1}}.\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}}\ge\frac{a+b+c+3}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}.$$
How can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way.

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)(a+b+c+abc)}{(ab+1)(a+b+c+abc)}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab+1}+c(a+b)}{a+b+c+abc}}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\tfrac{\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab+1}+\frac{c^2(a+b)^2}{c(a+b)}}{a+b+c+abc}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\tfrac{\frac{(a+b+c(a+b))^2}{ab+1+c(a+b)}}{a+b+c+abc}}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a+b+c(a+b)}{2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}=\tfrac{a+b+c+3}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}}.$$

Comment: It is very nice, indeed. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more time to accept the answer. I will choose this solution but the  idea using Holder is good as well.

Comment: @TATAbox You may upvote it and accept it. Now you only accept it. The current only one upvote belongs to me.

Comment: Yes, I need at least 15 reputation

Comment: @River Li, could you please help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725605/a-b-c-ge-0-abcabc-4-prove-that-sum-cyc-sqrt-fracabcab-ge-3?rq=1

Comment: @TATAbox I think it has a nice proof. But I don't find it now.

Comment: I saw some ideas but they are uncompleted solutions.

Comment: Can downvoter explain your step?

Answer (score 2):

By Holder $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+b+4c)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}=\sqrt{\frac{8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5ab)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5ab)\right)^3(a+b+c+abc)\geq(a+b+c+3)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$,where $v>0$(we obtain $v=1$),  $abc=w^3$

and for any polynomial $p(x)$ let $C(p)$ it's a coefficient before greatest power of $x$.

We need to prove that
$$8(9u^2+9v^2)^3(3uv^2+w^3)\geq(3u+3v)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+v^2)(3u+3c)^3$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=24(u^2+v^2)^3(3uv^2+w^3)-(u+v)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+v^2)(u+c)^3.$$
But $$C(f)=-(u+v)^2C\left(\sum_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+v^2)(u+c)^3\right)=-(u+v)^2C\left(\sum_{cyc}(3u-c)^2ab(u+c)^3\right)=$$
$$=-(u+v)^2C\left(\sum_{cyc}(9u^2-6uc+c^2)ab(u^3+3u^2c+3uc^2+c^3)\right)=$$
$$=-(u+v)^2C\left(\sum_{cyc}ab(c^5-6uc^4+3uc^4)\right)=-(u+v)^2C\left(\sum_{cyc}w^3(a^4-3ua^3)\right)=$$
$$=-(u+v)^2(12u-9u)=-3u(u+v)^2<0,$$ which says that $f$ is a concave function, which gives that it's enough to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for an extremal value of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Let $c=0$ and $b=\frac{3}{a},$ where $a>0$.

Thus, after this substitution to $$8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5ab)\right)^3(a+b+c+abc)\geq(a+b+c+3)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3$$ we obtain:
$$a^{12}-10a^{11}+68a^{10}-192a^9+1077a^8-2736a^7+5049a^6-8208a^5+$$
$$+9693a^4-5184a^3+5508a^2-2430a+729\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$a^{12}-10a^{11}+68a^{10}-192a^9+1077a^8-2736a^7+5049a^6-8208a^5+$$
$$+9693a^4-5184a^3+5508a^2-2430a+729=$$
$$=\left(a^{12}-10a^{11}+68a^{10}-192a^9+177a^8\right)+$$
$$+\left(900a^8-2736a^7+5049a^6-8208a^5+5652a^4\right)+$$
$$+\left(4041a^4-5184a^3+5508a^2-2430a+729\right)>0.$$
2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=a$ and $c=\frac{3-a^2}{2a},$ where $0<a\leq\sqrt3.$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(a-1)^4\left(a^{12}+40^{11}+130a^{10}+392a^9+887a^8+1040a^7+2044a^6+656a^5+927a^4-56a^3+98a^2-24a+9\right)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much. Uvw method is powerful.

Comment: I am really curious how to find the yield $a+b+4c$ in the first Holder step? The equality is $a=b=c=1$ which is general.

Comment: @TATA box It's the Bacteria's method.

Comment: Could you please tell more detail about it ? Thank you.

Comment: @TATA box I posted something. See this.

Comment: Can downvoter explain me your step?

Comment: I need a idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743266/a-b-c0abc-3-prove-that-sum-sqrt-fracab2abc-ge-frac3-sqrt6

Comment: @TATA box  I still have no a solution.

Comment: I tried to use contradiction method but it seems hard.

Answer (score 1):

How we can get $(a+b+4c)^3$ in the following Holder's step?
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+b+4c)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}=\sqrt{\frac{8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5ab)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+4c)^3}}.$$
We need to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}\geq\frac{a+b+c+3}{\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}},$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives such that $ab+ac+bc=3$.

Let $c=0$ and $a=b=\sqrt3$.

Thus, should be $$2\sqrt[4]3+\frac{\sqrt[4]{12}}{2}-\frac{2\sqrt3+3}{\sqrt[4]{12}}>0.$$
But $$2\sqrt[4]3+\frac{\sqrt[4]{12}}{2}-\frac{2\sqrt3+3}{\sqrt[4]{12}}=0.0896...$$
Now,for $k\geq0$  by Holder $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+kc)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+kc)^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+b+kc)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+kc)^3}}=\sqrt{\frac{8\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+(k+1)ab)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+kc)^3}}.$$
Holder it's the following.

> Let $a_i>0$, $b_i>0$,$\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Prove that:
> $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^{\alpha}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^{\beta}\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_i^{\alpha}b_i^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}\right)^{\alpha+\beta}.$$

The equality occurs, when $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)||(b_1,b_2,...,b_n).$

Id est, in the previous Holder the equality occurs for
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{ab+1}},\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{bc+1}},\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{ca+1}}\right)||$$
$$||\left((a+b)^2(ab+1)(a+b+kc)^3,(b+c)^2(bc+1)(b+c+ka)^3,(c+a)^2(ca+1)(c+a+kb)^3\right),$$ which gives
$$\sqrt{(a+b)(ab+1)}(a+b+kc)=\sqrt{(b+c)(bc+1)}(b+c+ka)=\sqrt{(c+a)(ca+1)}(c+a+kb),$$ which for $c=0$ and $a=b=\sqrt3$ gives:
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt3\cdot4}(2\sqrt3+0)=\sqrt{\sqrt3\cdot1}(\sqrt3+k\sqrt3)$$ or
$$k=4\sqrt2-1\approx4.65685$$ and we can try to use $k=4$, which leads to a right inequality.

Comment: I understand the motivation behind Holder using. Thank you @Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: @TATA box You are welcome!

Comment: Can downvoter explain me your step?

Comment: Could you please tell more? Why is downvoter?