# $a,b,c>0:a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $\sum\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{6}}{2}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, holder-inequality

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c>0:a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $$\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{bc+2}{bc+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ca+2}{ca+b}}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{6}}{2}.$$

I tried a lot without success.

By Holder, $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(ab+c)(ab+2)^2\ge (ab+bc+ca+6)^3,$$
which leads to wrong inequality at $a=b=0.96$
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(ab+c)(ab+2)^2(a+b)^3\ge (\sum_{cyc}(ab+2)(a+b))^3=(3q-3r+12)^3$$ is not good enough.

Also, by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4(ab+2)}{3(ab+c)+2(ab+2)}=4\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+2}{3c+5ab+4},$$which implies $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+2}{3c+5ab+4}\ge \frac{3}{4}.$$The last inequality is not true when $a=b\rightarrow 1.5$

By homogenizing, we need to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{13ab+4(ca+cb)+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3ab+ca+cb+c^2}}\ge \frac{9\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
Is there an idea called "isolated fudging" to prove the OP? I really hope someone share it here. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1) Have you tried trig sub? 2) Where have you found this problem?

Comment: It is from my friend

Comment: You might try setting $u,v,w$ to the three radical expressions and solving for $a,b,c$ in terms of them. Then seeing what the conditions on $a,b,c$ say about $u,v,w$. (I don't know if it will be helpful, but it might spark some different thoughts.)

Comment: @above, I tried but it is very complicated. The problem is really tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the isolated fudging.

It suffices to prove that, for all $a, b, c > 0$,
$$\frac{2}{3\sqrt 6}\sqrt{\frac{ab + 2(a + b + c)^2/9}{ab + c(a + b + c)/3}}\ge \frac{12(a^2 + b^2) + 32ab + 35c(a + b)}{24(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 102(ab + bc + ca)}. \tag{1}$$
(Summing cyclically on (1), the desired result follows.)

(1) can be proved by Buffalo Way (BW).

Comment: Thank you. I saw you used it before. Could you please tell me how to find it?

Comment: @TATAbox Use the method of unknown coefficients. I think it is often not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi could you please describe how you used undetermined coefficients here in order to arrive at something provable by BW?

Comment: @Sgg8 It is a long story. You may see the comment in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248347/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-frac1-sqrt2a25ab2b2-geq-sqrt-frac3/4248868#4248868).

Comment: @RiverLi Could you please help me give isolated fudging? $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{\dfrac{a(a+b+c)}{3}+4bc}{\dfrac{4a(a+b+c)}{3}+bc}}\ge 3.$$

Comment: @TATAbox Did you post it as a question?

Comment: I saw it in AOPS and I remember your similar answer.

Comment: @TATAbox I fail to use isolated fudging.

Comment: The equality case seems strange. I checked it by let $a=b$ and I saw true inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following reasoning will help.

By Holder $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab+2}{ab+c}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)^2(c+8)^3}{(ab+c)^2}}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)^2(c+8)^3}{(ab+c)^2}}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)(c+8)}{ab+c}\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)^2(c+8)^3}{(ab+c)^2}}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$2\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)(c+8)}{ab+c}\right)^3\geq27\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(ab+2)^2(c+8)^3}{(ab+c)^2},$$ which seems true.

It's true for $b=a$, $c=3-2a$, where $0<a<\frac{3}{2}.$

Also, it's true for $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $b=3-a$, where $0<a<3$.

I think, $uvw$ can kill it, but it's very complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The Holder yield is strange.

Comment: Which software did you use to check? My program is not good enough.

Comment: @TATA box Calculator and Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Could you please help me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743736/if-abbcca-1-prove-sqrt5a5b8ab-sqrt5c5b8cb-sqrt5a5c8ac-ge-3? Thanks.

Comment: @TATA box I tried. It quits very ugly.