# How to prove $\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{2}\ge\frac{a^3(b+c)+b^3(c+a)+c^3(a+b)}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2abc}.$?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sums-of-squares

If $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c,>0$ then prove
$$\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{2}\ge\frac{a^3(b+c)+b^3(c+a)+c^3(a+b)}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2abc}.$$

I'm looking for a simple proof which student could full it in during test time.

I've tried to show it in SOS form and here is what I got \begin{align*}    
    f(a,b,c)&=(ab+bc+ca)\left(\sum_{cyc}a^2.\sum_{cyc}a-2abc\right)^2-4\left(a^3(b+c)+b^3(c+a)+c^3(a+b)\right)^2\\
    &=(ab+bc+ca)\prod_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\left( b+c-a \right) ^2}+4\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{b^3c^3\left( b-c \right) ^2}\ge 0.
\end{align*}
It is not nice as I expected. Can we make it more optimal ?

All idea is welcome.

Comment: Did you try $uvw$?

Comment: Yes, $uvw$ kills it immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $uvw$ is the best option here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

By multiplying $\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$ for the OP, it is sufficient to prove$$(ab+bc+ca)\left[(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2abc\right]\ge 2\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\sum_{cyc}a^3(b+c) \tag{*}.$$Apply AM-GM as$$2\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\sum_{cyc}(b+c)a^3\le \sum_{cyc}a^3\left[(b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca\right] \tag{1}.$$The result follows... Can you end it now ?

---

Indeed, notice that$$\sum_{cyc}a^3(b+c)^2=(ab+bc+ca)\left(ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)-2abc\right),$$which implies\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{cyc}a^3\left((b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca)\right)\\
    &=(ab+bc+ca)\left(a^3+b^3+c^3+ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)-2abc\right)\\
    &=(ab+bc+ca)\left((a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2abc\right) \tag{2}.
\end{align*}
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get desired $(*).$

The proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=t>0;c=0$ or $abc$ and cyclic permutations.

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Comment: Thanks. I am feel upset about a downvote.

Comment: @TATAbox Already (+1). The strange downvote occurs often. So just take it easy.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, it is better if the downvoter explain the reason and I will improve it

Comment: Very nice using AM-GM

Comment: Could you please give an proof for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725605/a-b-c-ge-0-abcabc-4-prove-that-sum-cyc-sqrt-fracabcab-ge-3 ?

Comment: @Dragonboy that problem might be too hard for me. I have no proof